# Is there an easy way to import a text file with tuples as a list or array of tuples in Python?

Tags: python

So I have generated some data for a coordinate prediction task, the data looks like this:

```
(0, 0),(-1, 0),(-1, -1),(-2, -1),(-2, -2),(-3, -2),(-3, -3),(-3, -4)
(-3, -5),(-3, -4),(-2, -4),(-2, -3),(-2, -2),(-2, -1),(-2, 0),(-2, 1),(-2, 2),(-2, 3),(-2, 4)
(-2, 5),(-2, 4),(-3, 4),(-3, 3),(-3, 2),(-3, 1),(-3, 0),(-3, -1),(-3, -2)
(-3, -3)
```

As you can see the amount of columns in each row is not the same, because of this I have some isues with easily importing this using something like numpy or pandas. I also tried splitting lines but due to the comma inside the tuple and the comma being the delimiter it was not easy (for me) to retrieve the tuples into a list. The output I'd like would be something like this:

```
data = [[(0, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, -1), ...], 
        [(-3, -5), (-3, -4), (-2, -4), ...],
         ...]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: Clarification

Each line represents a path, where the coordinates are the coordinates the agent (in this case) walked across. I want to try and predict what the coordinate will be 3 steps later given the last 3 steps. For this I need to preprocess the data so that I have a list of lists of tuples where each inner list represents a path, with the path being a list of tuples.

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Code will be like this: `data = [literal_eval(s.strip()) for s in file]`

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is. Each line is a tuple literal, which can be directly evaluated to produce a tuple of tuples. Do you have any restrictions on the output type other than a nested tuple, e.g. does it have to be a ``List[List[Tuple]]``, a ``numpy.array``, ...?

Comment: I tried to clarify the problem in my EDIT 1: @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert each line into a list and convert to Python objects using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
s = """(0, 0),(-1, 0),(-1, -1),(-2, -1),(-2, -2),(-3, -2),(-3, -3),(-3, -4)
(-3, -5),(-3, -4),(-2, -4),(-2, -3),(-2, -2),(-2, -1),(-2, 0),(-2, 1),(-2, 2),(-2, 3),(-2, 4)
(-2, 5),(-2, 4),(-3, 4),(-3, 3),(-3, 2),(-3, 1),(-3, 0),(-3, -1),(-3, -2)
(-3, -3)"""


import ast
coords = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    importList = ast.literal_eval('[%s]' % line)
    coords += importList

print(len(coords))
```

Output:

```
29
```